# Changing language dynamically DateTimePicker jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I want to dynamically change the language of the DateTimePicker jQuery Plug-in ([http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/](http://http:/http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)) and I'm getting an "undefined" error for the `lang1` inside the last plug-in call:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Datatimepicker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.datetimepicker.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="datetimepicker" type="text" placeholder="Datetimerpicker">
    <input id="lang" type="text" placeholder="language" value="en"><div class="select">select language</div>
    <script>
            var lang1;

        $(".select").click(function(){
        lang = $('#lang').val();
        lang1 = '"'+lang+'"';
        return lang1
        });

        $(".select").click(function(){
            console.log(lang1);
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            lang: lang1
        })
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Shouldn't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined two click handlers which you expect to somewhat magically exchange the lang1 variable.

Probably you intended this:

```
    $(".select").click(function(){
        var lang = $('#lang').val(); // 1
        console.log(lang); // 2
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({ lang: lang }); // 3
    });
```

1. Get the current lang value from input field `#lang`
2. Log it to the console
3. Initialize the datepicker to use the language `lang`.

Comment: I used two event handlers to solve another issue I had before ( I will handle that and do as you say). But please note that my Datepicker is not the one you refer to (please see link above). Nevertheless, I get lang1 inside the second event handler (I know that because console.log outputs fine) but not inside the plug-in call. And that is what is messing with my head.

Comment: @PauloJaneiro: got it. I read too fast, thought that you used the JQueryUI datepicker. I correct the answer.

Comment: It works fine using your code, thank you! But can you explain why in my code lang1 exists in the console.log inside the second event handler but doesn't work inside the plug-in call ? By using a global variable declared outside any function shouldn't that make it?

Comment: `lang1` is a string with begins and ends with `"`. I assume that your datepicker plugin expects the unquoted language value (i.e. `lang`). I also would recommend not to use global variables to interchange values (`lang` and `lang1` defined in your event handler function 1 are global). Besides many reason to not use globals it is not reliable that your second event handler function is notified after the first one.